# How to create cascading droplist for Sitecore Form

Tags: sitecore-forms

I have a requirement to create a cascading dropdown for country and state.When a country is selected the states are populated automatically.
How to accomplish the same for Sitecore Form?

Comment: Tried this "https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/11699/changing-the-datasource-for-a-dropdown-list-field-in-a-form-on-a-page"?

Answer (score 3):

I got the same requirement and I have done some customization for this.

**Step 1:** Go to core database and under this location (/sitecore/client/Applications/FormsBuilder/Components/Layouts/PropertyGridForm/PageSettings/Settings) create a new control by copying DropDownList and name it CascadeDropDownList. Under this new control, add some text box parameters under ListItems for binding the second drop down list.

[image]

In each text box parameter, you need to fill these field values as per your parameter name.

[image]

And make an entry of each parameter under ListItems like this.

[image]

**Step 2:** Create a new Model that will be inherited from DropDownListViewModel like this.

```
using System;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Models.Fields;

namespace Universal.Feature.Forms.CustomModels
{
    [Serializable]
    public class CascadeDropDownListViewModel : DropDownListViewModel
    {
        public virtual string SecondDropDownSelectedValue { get; set; }

        public string SecondDropListLabel { get; set; }

        public string SecondDropListValue { get; set; }

        public string SecondDropListText { get; set; }

        public string SecondDropListFieldName { get; set; }

        protected override void InitItemProperties(Item item)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(item, "item");
            base.InitItemProperties(item);

            SecondDropListLabel = item?.Fields[FormsConstants.ItemConstants.SecondDropListLabel]?.Value;
            SecondDropListValue = item?.Fields[FormsConstants.ItemConstants.SecondDropListValue]?.Value;
            SecondDropListText = item?.Fields[FormsConstants.ItemConstants.SecondDropListText]?.Value;
            SecondDropListFieldName = item?.Fields[FormsConstants.ItemConstants.SecondDropListFieldName]?.Value;
        }

        protected override void UpdateItemFields(Item item)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(item, "item");
            base.UpdateItemFields(item);

            var label = item.Fields[FormsConstants.ItemConstants.SecondDropListLabel];
            if (label != null)
            {
                label.SetValue(SecondDropListLabel, true);
            }

            var value = item.Fields[FormsConstants.ItemConstants.SecondDropListValue];
            if (value != null)
            {
                value.SetValue(SecondDropListValue, true);
            }

            var text = item.Fields[FormsConstants.ItemConstants.SecondDropListText];
            if (text != null)
            {
                text.SetValue(SecondDropListText, true);
            }

            var fieldName = item.Fields[FormsConstants.ItemConstants.SecondDropListFieldName];
            if (fieldName != null)
            {
                fieldName.SetValue(SecondDropListFieldName, true);        
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 3:** Create a view to binding the Model value.

```
@using Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Html
@model Universal.Feature.Forms.CustomModels.CascadeDropDownListViewModel

<div class="universalcascadingselectlist">
    <label for="@Html.IdFor(m => Model.Value)" class="@Model.LabelCssClass">@Html.DisplayTextFor(t => Model.Title)</label>
<select id="@Html.IdFor(m => Model.Value)" name="@Html.NameFor(m => Model.Value)" class="@Model.CssClass universalcascadingselectlist-ddn" data-sc-tracking="@Model.IsTrackingEnabled" data-sc-field-name="@Model.Name" @Html.GenerateUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(m => m.Value)>
    @if (Model.ShowEmptyItem)
    {
        <option label=" "></option>
    }@foreach (var item in Model.Items)
    {
        <option value="@item.Value" selected="@item.Selected">@item.Text</option>
    }
</select>
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Value)

<div class="child-ddl">
    <label for="@Html.IdFor(m => Model.SecondDropDownSelectedValue)" class="@Model.LabelCssClass">@Html.DisplayTextFor(t => Model.SecondDropListLabel)</label>
    <select id="@Html.IdFor(m => Model.SecondDropDownSelectedValue)" name="@Html.NameFor(m => Model.SecondDropDownSelectedValue)" class="universalcascadingselectlist-child-ddn" data-sc-tracking="@Model.IsTrackingEnabled" data-sc-text="@Model.SecondDropListText" data-sc-value="@Model.SecondDropListValue" data-sc-field-name="@Model.SecondDropListFieldName"></select>
</div>
```

**Step 4:** Now a JS call to get the state values by selecting a country. Or you can say by selecting the first dropdown value we are getting values and filling the second dropdown value.

```
let UniversalCascadingSelectList = function (selectListComponent) {
this.selectListComponent = selectListComponent;
this.parentSelectList = this.selectListComponent.querySelector('.universalcascadingselectlist-ddn');
this.childSelectList = this.selectListComponent.querySelector('.universalcascadingselectlist-child-ddn');
this.textField = this.childSelectList.getAttribute("data-sc-text");
this.valueField = this.childSelectList.getAttribute("data-sc-value");
};

UniversalCascadingSelectList.prototype.Init = function () {
var _this = this;

_this.PopulateChildList();

this.parentSelectList.addEventListener('change', function () {
    _this.PopulateChildList();
});
};

UniversalCascadingSelectList.prototype.PopulateChildList = function () {
var childSelectList = this.childSelectList;

//get the value from select list 1
var itemId = this.parentSelectList.value;

//pass it via the get, as querystring parameter
$.get("/universalapi/Feature/Forms/CascadeDropdownList/SelectItems", { itemId: itemId, textFieldName: this.textField, valueFieldName: this.valueField }, function (data, status) {

    //clear and load SelectList2
    childSelectList.innerHTML = "";

    if (status === "success") {
        $.each(data, function (key, entry) {
            var addedOption = document.createElement("option");
            addedOption.text = entry.Text;
            addedOption.value = entry.Value;
            childSelectList.add(addedOption, 1);
        });
    }
});
};

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
let selectLists = document.querySelectorAll('.universalcascadingselectlist');

if (selectLists) {
    selectLists.forEach(function (selectListComponent) {
        // Construct new FeaturedData
        var selectList = new UniversalCascadingSelectList(selectListComponent);

        // Init functionality on load
        selectList.Init();
    });
}
});
```

**Step 5:** And a controller to get the data.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Sitecore.Data;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;

namespace Universal.Feature.Forms.Controllers.CascadeDropdownList
{
    public class CascadeDropdownListController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult SelectItems(string itemId, string textFieldName, string valueFieldName)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(itemId))
                return new JsonResult();

            if(Sitecore.Context.Database == null)
                return new JsonResult();

            var parentItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(ID.Parse(itemId));

            if (parentItem == null)
                return new JsonResult();

            var items = parentItem.GetChildren().Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = GetValueForStandardFields(textFieldName, x) ?? x.Fields[textFieldName].Value, Value = GetValueForStandardFields(valueFieldName, x) ?? x.Fields[valueFieldName].Value });

            return Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    
        private string GetValueForStandardFields(string fieldName, Item item)
        {
            if (fieldName.Equals("ID", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                return item.ID.ToString();

            if (fieldName.Equals("Name", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                return item.Name;

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 6:** Make an entry in master database under this location (/sitecore/system/Settings/Forms/Field Types/Lists). Make a copy of existing DropDown List and name it Cascade Dropdown List and fill the required fields.

[image]

That's it and under Sitecore the control will be listed

[image]

and you can enter the values.